# Spring framework - class loader relationship

Tags: java, spring, classloader

I am having a problem which is probably related to the Spring / class loader relationship.

I will apologise for the verbosity of the question now.

I have a number of legacy java applications which were originally written and intended to run within a dedicated JVM. We decided upon examination of the resource usage that efficiencies could be gained by running multiple applications within a single JVM. Within that context I wrote a container manager specifically designed for our environment which is capable of running each application within a container (or sandbox). The basis of this ability to isolate the containers is of course a custom class loader.

All works well until we came across an application which uses the Spring framework. I have a Spring configuration file with fragments as below.

```
<bean id="MDDStructurPackager" class="abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000">
    <property name="logger">
        <ref local="Logger"/>
    </property>
    <property name="realm">
        <value>unpack</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="Jakarta" class="abc.def.mdd.channel.corba.M2000AlarmChannel">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="MDDStructurPackager"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="interactionLayer">
        <ref local="MDDInteractionLayer"/>
    </property>
    <property name="logger">
        <ref local="Logger"/>
    </property>
    <property name="tempFile" value="/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/var/cache/dat/Huawei_M2000_Jakarta.dat"/>
    <property name="host" value="M2000Jakarta.ior"/>
    <property name="irpReference" value="clarity"/>
    <property name="name" value="M2000Jakarta"/>
    <property name="realm" value="Jakarta"/>
 <property name="natAddress" value="99.999.99.9" />
</bean>
```

---

The following is a fragment from the log file as Spring is instantiating the beans.

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:162) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'MDDStructurPackager'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:378) - Creating instance of bean 'MDDStructurPackager'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:453) - Eagerly caching bean 'MDDStructurPackager' to allow for resolving potential circular references

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'Logger'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:242) - Getting BeanInfo for class [abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:258) - Caching PropertyDescriptors for class [abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'class' of type [java.lang.Class]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'colectionDate' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'component' of type [abc.def.mdd.msg.MDDComponent]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'fileType' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'listCommonWords' of type [java.util.ArrayList]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'listHeader' of type [java.util.ArrayList]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'logger' of type [abc.def.mdd.logger.Logger]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'mapDelimiter' of type [java.util.Map]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'mapElement' of type [java.util.Map]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'namePackager' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'nameSpaceXMLSchema' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'nodeName' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'packageXMLSchema' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'processingLayerListener' of type [abc.def.mdd.channel.ProcessingLayerListener]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'realm' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (CachedIntrospectionResults.java:267) - Found bean property 'statesObject' of type [java.lang.String]

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:406) - Finished creating instance of bean 'MDDStructurPackager'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:162) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ListAlarmChannel'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:378) - Creating instance of bean 'ListAlarmChannel'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:453) - Eagerly caching bean 'ListAlarmChannel' to allow for resolving potential circular references

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:162) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'Jakarta'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:378) - Creating instance of bean 'Jakarta'

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'MDDStructurPackager'

INFO: CORBA_HUAWEI_M2KJKT_ALARM (23447542): Added "/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/lib/logkit-1.2.jar" to the class path.

INFO: CORBA_HUAWEI_M2KJKT_ALARM (23447542): Added "/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/lib/avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar" to the class path.

INFO: CORBA_HUAWEI_M2KJKT_ALARM (23447542): Added "/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/lib/concurrent-1.3.2.jar" to the class path.

INFO: CORBA_HUAWEI_M2KJKT_ALARM (23447542): Added "/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/lib/antlr-2.7.2.jar" to the class path.

DEBUG [South Agent 1] (ConstructorResolver.java:195) - 
    Ignoring constructor [public abc.def.mdd.channel.corba.M2000AlarmChannel(
                              java.lang.String,
                              int,
                              java.lang.String,
                              java.lang.String,
                              com.citycorp.mdd.msg.MDDComponent
                            ) throws java.lang.Exception
                         ] 
    of bean 'Jakarta': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'Jakarta' defined in file [/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/etc/HUAWEI_M2KJKT_ALARM.xml]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: 
    Could not convert constructor argument value of type [abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000] to required type [java.lang.String]:
 
    Failed to convert value of type [abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000] to required type [java.lang.String]; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Cannot convert value of type [abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000] to required type [java.lang.String]: 
    no matching editors or conversion strategy found

---

The following are the signatures of the constructors for the abc.def.mdd.channel.corba.M2000AlarmChannel class:

public M2000AlarmChannel( MDDComponent componenet )

public M2000AlarmChannel( String host, int port, String username, String password, MDDComponent componenet )

The class abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000 implements MDDComponent (bean MDDStructurPackager).

---

---

As you can see, Spring is instantiating some of the beans ie. MDDStructurPackager without problem.

The problem is instantiating the 'Jakarta' bean.

The implications of the lines:

Error creating bean with name 'Jakarta' defined in file [/opt/app/abcdef/rt_dev/etc/HUAWEI_M2KJKT_ALARM.xml]:

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]:

Could not convert constructor argument value of type [abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000] to required type [java.lang.String]:


are not clear. I am not sure the reasons for the type confusion when attempting to determine the appropriate constructor. It is possible that the problem is associated with the loading of the interface MDDComponent. If it was loaded twice, by different class loaders which are not related in the class loader hierarchy you could imagine problems associated with determining the correct constructor.

Any ideas gratefully received, I am grasping at straws.

Thanks
Bryan

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, it sounds like Spring is attempting to instantiate the object with this constructor:

```
public M2000AlarmChannel(String host, int port, String username, String password, MDDComponent componenet)
```

Looks like Spring is confused on which constructor to use, possibly because both constructors have a `MDDComponent` parameter  (in a way, both constructors have this as their last parameter, I'm curious if that has something to do with the logic that Spring uses in determining which constructor to use. Anyway...).

According to the [Spring manual](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection), there are parameters you can add to the `<constructor-arg>` element to help the container resolve which constructor to use:

You can add "type":

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
  <constructor-arg type="int" value="7500000"/>
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="42"/>
</bean>
```

or you can add an index:

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="7500000"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" value="42"/>
</bean>
```

(You can probably specify both, if you really want to)

Adding one or both of these should help Spring resolve which constructor to use.

As a corollary, if this doesn't help, can you simply change the XML definition to pass in the parameters required for the other constructor, the one Spring is attempting to use?

BTW, it might make your question a lot more readable to use the quote tags within WMD.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the application runs fine standalone, ie. not within a container.

Comment: You mean "standalone" as in using Spring, but not your home-brewed app container?

Comment: Then you might want to look into checking if somehow a different version of the class abc.def.mdd.channel.corba.M2000AlarmChannel is on the classpath

Comment: have you tried isolating this app, e.g. running it by itself in your container? If you are running other apps in the same JVM, shut down all and try this one on its own.

Comment: Yes, we are running only one app in the container.

Comment: Have you added the 'type' and/or 'index' attributes as I mentioned above and are still getting the same errors?

Comment: The client site is in another country (Indonesia). There are difficulties, I am working on it.

Comment: I am trying to construct an environment to duplicate (logically at least) the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it is.  The first constructor argument you pass to the Jakarta object is of type abc.def.mdd.msg.alarm.huawei.MDDPackagerAlarmM2000, but the ctor wants a String.  Make the types match properly.

It reads as a straight-forward message.  What am I missing?

I'll assume from the package structure that those are your classes.  True?

Comment: But isn't the point that his arguments *do* match a constructor? Just that Spring doesn't seem to think so?

Comment: I must be tired.  Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: The other part of the question of course is which constructor is it actually considering. According to the log it has decided to ignore one of them, as it should. Why does it think it needs a String argument? Or is the String requirement an artefact of choosing the wrong constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in control of the `AlarmChannel` class? If so, can you roll a new version which has a print statement in the constructor (also you could use `try-catch` within a `static` initializer to get a stack trace from where the class is being initialized from)?

That way, you might get some idea of whether there are duplicate classes involved

Also in the Spring config file you could cause the `ClassLoader` to be printed out using a `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` - this might also shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Unfortunately, I control the container but not the software that is being executed. I was able to get the constructor signatures and the Spring fragments but I will not be able to access/modify any of the executing code.

Comment: Can you subclass AlarmChannel and add the info, or is it final?

Comment: I have no direct access to the software running in the container. Anything that I do has to be done in the container manager.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; sorry. Then how do you know what the contructor signatures of the AlarmChannel look like?

Can you debug the Spring container where it is actually taking the class name and trying to find the contructor? Or roll your own app context with appropriate logging statements?

Comment: I asked the vendor for the constructor signatures but I cannot get full source code. I am trying to construct an environment to duplicate (logically at least) the environment.

Comment: Have you verified that the class signatures are correct using javap? Maybe Spring is right and they are wrong?